Cassandra driver 2.1.10.2 returns NoHostAvailableException when Hbase client is upgraded to 2.5.8
Cassandra is giving NoHostAvailableException when Hbase client is upgraded to 2.5.8 version and cassandra driver version used is 2.1.10.2
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4736) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.epsilon.cassandra.dao.AbstractCassandraDao.getCachedStatement(AbstractCassandraDao.java:484) ~[cassandraDataStore-0.0.2.50.jar:?]
        at com.epsilon.cassandra.dao.AbstractCassandraDao.doUpdateByCql(AbstractCassandraDao.java:120) ~[cassandraDataStore-0.0.2.50.jar:?]
        at com.epsilon.cassandra.dao.AbstractCassandraDao.doUpdateByNamedStatement(AbstractCassandraDao.java:107) ~[cassandraDataStore-0.0.2.50.jar:?]

When we downgraded the hbase client version to 2.1.10.2 we dont see this issue

we are using com.google.guava:guava :16.0.1 version. Not sure if it is conflicting

When we downgraded the hbase client version to 2.1.10.2 we dont see this issue

It looks like your environment is running legacy versions and I think that would explain why you are running into compatibility issues.
HBase client 2.5.8 is the latest version released in March 2024.
On the other hand, you're using the Cassandra Java driver 2.1.10.2 which was released 8 years ago (2016) so it would make sense that it only works with the older HBase client 2.1.10 from 4 years ago instead of the latest version. Cheers!
